# What is the Rubyist way to catch an exception raised in a rescue block?

Tags: ruby, exception

Suppose I have the following:

```
begin
  raise 'Exception!'
rescue => e
  puts "Rescued exception: #{e.message}"
  raise 'Something I did in this block raised an exception!'
end
```

What's the Rubyist way to catch the second exception? Is it best to wrap the entire thing in another begin-rescue block, or is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: If you're in Rails there's also `rescue_from`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't speak to *the* Rubyist way, but here's *a* Rubyist's way:

Make the rescue code as error proof as possible. If it isn't possible to make it so error proof that exceptions are vanishingly rare, then rather than beginning a nest of rescue blocks inside of rescue blocks, call another method that handles its own exceptions, e.g.:

```
def foo
  1/0
rescue
  complicated_foo_error_handler
end

private

def complicated_foo_error_handler
  # handle foo errors
rescue
  complicated_complicated_foo_error_handler_error_handler
end

def complicated_complicated_foo_error_handler_error_handler
  # handle complicated_foo_error_handler errors
rescue
  STDERR.puts 'I give up!'
  exit false
end
```

Comment: That assumes you want to handle the exception inside the handler. Sometimes you want to propagate the exception from a rescue, or raise a different exception that describes the problem more accurately for the caller. I'm not 100% sure what OP needs.